# How to add duplicate rows in a specified manner sequentially in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame where I want to replicate and rows in the following manner

```
 d=pd.DataFrame({"col1":["a","b","a","d"],
                "col2":[12,13,14,16],
                 "col3":[1,2,3,4]})
```

required output:
want to copy rows a1, a2, b1, b2

```
col1  col2  col3
a      12    1
a1     12    1
a2     12    1
b      13    2 
b1     13    2
b2     13    2
a      14    3
a1     14    3 
a2     14    3
d      16    4
d1     16    4
d2     16    4
```

Comment: What is the difference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674466/how-to-add-multiple-rows-in-a-specified-position-with-modification-in-python/63674512#63674512) ?

Comment: Create `d['subgroup']=d.col1.ne(d.col1.shift()).cumsum()
` , then use this a new key for all groupby , and it will be the same as anky's answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add multiple rows in a specified position with modification in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674466/how-to-add-multiple-rows-in-a-specified-position-with-modification-in-python)

Comment: Why did you ask a question twice? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674466/)

Comment: i had a , b , a in my "col1" column which was resulting in the output as a ,a1 a2 , b , b1 , b2 , a3 , a4 , a5 @Meee

Comment: i had a , b , a in my "col1" column which was resulting in the output as a ,a1 a2 , b , b1 , b2 , a3 , a4 , a5 @anky

Comment: Two very very similar questions. Do not do this. @Amit

Comment: You shouldn't have ticked it if you were not convinced @Amit. You could have just upvoted that answer.

Comment: i asked in the wrong way .. but the question was answered which was asked . i wanted to appriciate the efforts @VisheshMangla

Comment: Otherwise you may also like "explode" in pandas but you need to figure out how to use it for your specific usecase https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: @Amit i have updated with another solution in the previous question (it wasnt a big change) , although you were right about asking a new question ince the original was answered (but there are many answers on SO where you would find a solution to create a seperate grouper for repeating values later in a series) :-) Hope you are fine